# How to display a image in the browser with cir2 raw data type?

Tags: image, browser

I have an image that is 12 MB and has type Canon CR2 raw image. If i usually drag any jpg or gif image in the firefox web browser, the browser displays the pic but drag drop of this image displays nothing. In fact a popup window shows that reads:You have chosen to open a binary file. Would you like to save it.

I am trying to drag and drop images on my website to upload to server and display them in the browser. How do i fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAW images usually can not be understood by software other than the manufacturer's (or specialized RAW converters/workflow tools). Firefox has a set of image formats it can display - RAW formats are not among them.

Convert your image to JPEG or PNG - then you're go.

Also, this question does not seem to be programming related...